# Trying to use JFileChooser to get a file path

Tags: java, netbeans, jfilechooser

I followed the instructions on https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-filechooser.html and created a new java file in my project.
It looks like this now

```
TuringSim > Source Packages > turingsim > TuringSim.java
TuringSim > Source Packages > turingsim.resources > ChooseFile.java
```

ChooseFile.java containing all the steps from the site.
Now all I want to do is get the file path from ChooseFile.java to TuringSim.java
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create some kind of public setter, public field or use file chooser from TurningSim. But first of all, let yourself familiarize with Object Oriented Programming related stuff...